# Login form in collapsible panel extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, login-control, collapsiblepanelextender

I want to display login form on a collapsible panel extender for login a user.
Please help me for this Ajax problem.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Show some code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer but. It is working only with IE. It is not working with Firefox. Your comments are honored.

//add first script manager

Then.....

```
           <div class="secpanel">
           <table id="login">
                <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                       &nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User name:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="usrtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       &nbsp;</td>
                   <td>
                       &nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="passtxt" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       &nbsp;</td>
                   <td>
                       &nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="loginbtn" runat="server" Text="Login" ValidationGroup="g1" 
                        onclick="loginbtn_Click"/></td>
            </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                           ErrorMessage="Please enter user name" ControlToValidate="usrtxt" 
                           ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="g1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                           ErrorMessage="Please enter password" ControlToValidate="passtxt" 
                           ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="g1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                       <asp:Label ID="err" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                       &nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        &nbsp;</td>
               </tr>

           </table>
          </div>
        </asp:Panel>


             <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" TargetControlID="secpanel" CollapseControlID="fstpanel" ExpandDirection="Vertical" TextLabelID="lbl" CollapsedText="Click to login" ExpandedText="Hide" CollapsedSize="0" ExpandedSize="200" ExpandControlID="fstpanel" Collapsed="true" ScrollContents="false" runat="server">
             </asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

//code for the submit button

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hw"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Login where Admin_name=@", con);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", usrtxt.Text);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", usrtxt.Text);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if((usrtxt.Text==dr.GetString(1)) && (passtxt.Text==dr.GetString(2)))
                {
                    Session["admin"]=dr.GetString(1);
                    Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    err.Text="You are not autorized";
                }
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It May be some browser problem. try out with another browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is incomplete. If you want to implement Collapsible Panel ...
You have to use two panels one for Header and another for Content. 
Finally set the options as below in Collapsible Panel Extender.

```
 <Ajax:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelext1" runat="server"   CollapseControlID="pnl1Head" Collapsed="true" ExpandControlID="pnl1Head" TextLabelID="lblMessage" CollapsedText="Show" ExpandedText="Hide" ImageControlID="imgArrows" ExpandDirection="Vertical" TargetControlID="pnl2Content" ScrollContents="True" ExpandedImage="../images/collapse_blue.jpg" CollapsedImage="../images/expand_blue.jpg"> </Ajax:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```